Does Peano Arithmetic implicitly describe a set?
Apologies if my language is incorrect. My question is that in the axiomatizations of PA I have seen, they implicitly posit a 'set' of natural numbers and then describe which elements belong to it. To my understanding PA is a set of axioms added to first order logic, and sets and membership are not described by FOL or PA. This leads me to the following questions

Do axioms like "0 is a natural number" imply there exists a set of natural numbers and zero is an element of it?

Can we describe this axiom only using the syntax of FOL? I've seen $(\exists n)(0=n)$ as a representation of this axiom, but i'm not sure what the variable $n$ is.


Apologies if my title or questions aren't formatted correctly.

EDIT: Thank you for the responses! I was conflating two separate formations of PA leading to the ill-posed question.

$0$ is a term in PA (as a first-order theory), not an axiom. See Peano arithmetic.

You may get the answer if you learn basic mathematical logic. The thing is that although $\mathsf{PA}$ itself cannot describe sets, a model of $\mathsf{PA}$ has the domain of discourse, which is a set of elements of the model. If you mean an internal description for set-like objects, you may move into its second-order conservative extension like $\mathsf{ACA}_0$.

It would be much better to quote a specific reference that you are having problems with. As things stand, your question doesn't make much sense: an axiomatization doesn't posit the existence of any of the sets that we interpret it as describing: it's just a a set of properties on putative members of those sets.

Do you still have a question that wasn't resolved by the earlier comments?  If yes, it's not clear to me what it is.

No! The comments cleared it up for me
